# Is there a binary package for php5-sqlite3 with fts3 enabled?

Tags: php, package-management, sqlite

I would like to have PHP with SQlite with FTS3 extension enabled, as noted in [Manual:SQLite - MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSQLite#Search_engine).

I'm somewhat confused about FTS3 support in the default Ubuntu packages;

from [Bug #229003 in sqlite3 (Ubuntu): “Build sqlite3 with fts3 fulltext search ”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sqlite3/+bug/229003):

> It would be great if ubuntu can ship with enabled fts3 too.

That bug seems to have been fixed in `karmic`, so from [Issue 448 - clementine-player - Clementine 0.4 does not start - A cross-platform music player based on Amarok 1.4 - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=448):

> That's strange - all of Ubuntu's sqlite3 packages have FTS3 enabled, even 3.6.23...

... so all should be fine - however, that doesn't seem to be the case for php5-sqlite package..

So, it seems,  that in order to enable FTS3 for PHP, I'd have to re-build SQlite (and possibly PHP) from source -  but I was hoping there's a package-like way to use precompiled binaries (as I'd like to make an install suggestion to an administrator of a server, and compiling from source will be too troublesome). Is there?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got an answer at [LInux: How to install FTS3 (for sqlite3) in PHP? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754212/linux-how-to-install-fts3-for-sqlite3-in-php) - and I guess, the answer is, there is no such binary package; things have to be compiled from source.